# Get duration/length in milliseconds of GIF file

Tags: android, kotlin, gif, android-glide

I know there are plenty of similar questions available on SO but most of them are using the MOVIE class, which is deprecated. Now Android suggests using the AnimatedImageDrawable class for GIFs but it doesn't provide any mechanism to get the duration/length of GIF.

Please do let me know if any mechanism is available for the same.